# ¿Cuál es el tamaño de este array simple?

Tags: java, array, poo

Si tengo un array de `misProfesores[2]`, ¿estoy almacenando 2 objetos profesor o 3?

Visto que empiezan desde 0, no sé si estoy guardando 3 o 2:

```
public class Curso {
    
    //Atributos
    private String nombre, fecha;
    //Y un mapa de Estudiantes
    private Map<String, Estudiante> misEstudiantes;
    //Tendrá una lista de profesores
    private Profesor[] misProfesores;

    public Curso(String nombre, String fecha) {
        
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.misEstudiantes = new HashMap<>();
        this.misProfesores = new Profesor [2];
    }
```

Comment: Al tener `misProfesores[2]`, indica que tendrás 2 posiciones en el array `misProfesores`, y como son 2 posiciones, puedes almacenar hasta 2 elementos.

Comment: Si tienes un array de tamaño (length) 2, almacena 2 objetos de la clase Profesor. Los índices de un array comienzan desde 0, por lo que en un array de tamaño 2, los índices válidos son 0 y 1. Es importante tener en cuenta siempre la diferencia entre longitud o length y numeración de los índices para evitar los típicos errores por uno (off-by-one errors).

Comment: Simplemente la numeración comienza por 0. No es que mágicamente haya más elementos. Hay lenguajes que empiezan por 1. Hipotéticamente podrías enumerar con letras comenzando por la **a**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queda explicado con claridad en la [Especificación del Lenguaje](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-10.html):

> In the Java programming language, arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are
> dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type `Object`
> (§4.3.2). All methods of class `Object` may be invoked on an array.
>
> An array object contains a number of variables. The number of
> variables may be zero, in which case the array is said to be empty.
> The variables contained in an array have no names; instead they are
> referenced by array access expressions that use non-negative integer
> index values. These variables are called the components of the array.
> If an array has `n` components, we say `n` is the length of the array;
> the components of the array are referenced using integer indices from
> `0` to `n - 1`, inclusive.
>
> All the components of an array have the same type, called the
> component type of the array. If the component type of an array is `T`,
> then the type of the array itself is written `T[]`.
>
> The component type of an array may itself be an array type. The
> components of such an array may contain references to subarrays. If,
> starting from any array type, one considers its component type, and
> then (if that is also an array type) the component type of that type,
> and so on, eventually one must reach a component type that is not an
> array type; this is called the element type of the original array, and
> the components at this level of the data structure are called the
> elements of the original array.
>
> There are some situations in which an element of an array can be an
> array: if the element type is `Object` or `Cloneable` or
> `java.io.Serializable`, then some or all of the elements may be
> arrays, because any array object can be assigned to any variable of
> these types.

---

> En el lenguaje de programación Java, las matrices son objetos
> (§4.3.1), se crean dinámicamente y pueden asignarse a variables de
> tipo `Object` (§4.3.2). Todos los métodos de la clase `Object` se
> pueden invocar en una matriz.
>
> Un objeto de matriz contiene una serie de variables. El número de
> variables puede ser cero, en cuyo caso se dice que la matriz está
> vacía. Las variables contenidas en una matriz no tienen nombres; en su
> lugar, se les hace referencia mediante expresiones de acceso a
> matrices que utilizan valores de índice enteros no negativos. Estas
> variables se denominan componentes del arreglo. Si una matriz tiene
> `n` componentes, decimos que `n` es la longitud de la matriz; se hace
> referencia a los componentes de la matriz utilizando índices enteros
> de `0` a `n - 1`, inclusive.
>
> Todos los componentes de un arreglo tienen el mismo tipo, llamado tipo
> de componente del arreglo. Si el tipo de componente de una matriz es
> `T`, entonces el tipo de la matriz en sí se escribe `T[]`.
>
> El tipo de componente de una matriz puede ser en sí mismo un tipo de
> matriz. Los componentes de tal arreglo pueden contener referencias a
> subarreglos. Si, a partir de cualquier tipo de matriz, se considera su
> tipo de componente, y luego (si ese también es un tipo de matriz) el
> tipo de componente de ese tipo, y así sucesivamente, finalmente se
> debe llegar a un tipo de componente que no es un tipo de matriz; esto
> se llama el tipo de elemento de la matriz original, y los componentes
> en este nivel de la estructura de datos se denominan elementos de la
> matriz original.
>
> Hay algunas situaciones en las que un elemento de una matriz puede ser
> una matriz: si el tipo de elemento es `Object` o `Cloneable` o
> `java.io.Serializable`, entonces algunos o todos los elementos pueden
> ser matrices, porque cualquier objeto de matriz se puede asignar a
> cualquier variable de estos tipos.

Vamos a retomar este párrafo:

> Si una matriz tiene `n` componentes, decimos que `n` es la longitud de
> la matriz; los componentes de la matriz se referencian utilizando
> índices enteros de `0` a `n - 1`, inclusive.

Así, en el caso de:

```
misProfesores[2]
```

Decimos que tiene `2` componentes, lo cuales se referencian utilizando índices enteros, partiendo desde `0` hasta `n-1`. Es decir, los índices posibles para `misProfesores` serán solamente `0` y `1`. En lenguaje coloquial: habrá dos profesores, uno en el índice `0` de la matriz, y otro en el índice `1`.

Comment: Yo dejaría solo la traducción puesto que la cita es bastante larga.

Comment: @Mateo gracias por tu comentario, pero a mi me gusta poner siempre el original y la traducción seguida, sobre todo porque eso me ha ayudado mucho a comprender la doc en inglés y creo que podría ayudar a otros. Saludos.

Comment: Me parece bien. Es solo una opinión.